# Where does virtualenvwrapper put python files in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I used virtualenvwrapper to make a virtual environment on windows and now I need to point my IDE to the python interpreter I created but I cannot find it. I can use workon from cmd but I can't find the actual location of the new interpreter.

Comment: Does `cdvirtualenv` work? It works on Linux. It's one of those commands in `virtualenvwrapper` why we love `virtualenvwrapper`. :-)

Comment: That takes you to the directory of all of the `virtualenvwrapper` scripts but not the scripts for environments created using `virtualenvwrapper` right? I found the default location of created environments to be `%userprofile%\Envs`

Comment: `cdvirtualenv` (at least on windows) goes to the `sys.exec_prefix` directory, which is the main python installation if you haven't activated a virtualenv. If you have activated a virtualenv it will go to the location of that virtualenv. Use the `virtualenvwrapper` command to get a list, and summary, of available commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the default location at %userprofile%\Envs

Answer (score 0):

The location is output when you create a new virtualenv:

```
C:\srv> mkvirtualenv foox
New python executable in c:\srv\venv\foox\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

afterwards you can get the location by activating the virtualenv and issuing the `cdvirtualenv` command.

As you've figured out, the default location is `%USERPROFILE%\Envs`, but it's recommended to set the `%WORKON_HOME%` environment variable to the folder where you want the virtualenvs created. `mkvirtualenv` looks at `%WORKON_HOME%` first, and sets it if you haven't defined it (from the top of `mkvirtualenv.bat`):

```
:defaults
    set "venvwrapper.original_args=%*"
    set "venvwrapper.default_workon_home=%USERPROFILE%\Envs"
    set "venvwrapper.scriptsdir=Scripts"

    :: make sure WORKON_HOME has a useful value
    if not defined WORKON_HOME  set "WORKON_HOME=%venvwrapper.default_workon_home%"
    set "venvwrapper.workon_home=%WORKON_HOME%"
```